# Android Load from SharedPreferences in background

Tags: android, asynchronous, sharedpreferences

I have the following code successfully loading from `SharedPreferences`

```
List<MyObject> oList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

// Get JSON Data from storage.
HashSet<String> oStrings = new HashSet<String>();
oStrings = (HashSet<String>) oSharedPrefs.getStringSet(IConstants.MY_OBJECT_LIST, null);

if (oStrings != null && oStrings.size() > 0)
{
  Gson oGson = new Gson();
  for (String strJSONObject : oStrings)
  {
    MyObject oObject = oGson.fromJson(strJSONObject, MyObject.class);
    oList.add(oObject);
  }
}

return oList;
```

The problem is, this is running on the UI thread & as the `SharedPreferences` JSON strings get larger, this can cause my app to pause for a few seconds.

How would I go about loading this data in the background then retrieving the object list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for this:

```
public class LoadFromShared extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<MyObject>>{
  private OnLoadingDoneListener mListener;
  public interface OnLoadingDoneListener{
    public void onDone(List<MyObject> result);
  }

  public void setOnLoadingDoneListener(OnLoadingDoneListener listener){
    this.mListener = listener;
  }

  @Override
  protected List<MyObject> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    List<MyObject> oList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    // Get JSON Data from storage.
    HashSet<String> oStrings = new HashSet<String>();
    oStrings = (HashSet<String>) oSharedPrefs.getStringSet(IConstants.MY_OBJECT_LIST, null);
    if (oStrings != null && oStrings.size() > 0)
    {
      Gson oGson = new Gson();
      for (String strJSONObject : oStrings)
      {
        MyObject oObject = oGson.fromJson(strJSONObject, MyObject.class);
        oList.add(oObject);
      }
    }
    return oList;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(List<MyObject> result) {
    if(mListener!=null={
      mListener.onDone(result);
    }
  };
}
```

An then in your main:

```
LoadFromShared loader = new LoadFromShared();
loader.setOnLoadingDoneListener(new OnLoadingDoneListener(){
  @Override
  onDone(List<MyObject> result){
    //do your stuff here
  }  
};);

loader.execute();
```

No guarantee for correct typing ;)

Comment: Thanks, one more thing I'm struggling with... How would this work if I this code was in a utility class. So the activity called `Utils.doLoad(oSharedPreferences)` then the `Utils` contains the Async task... The original `Utils.doLoad()` returned the list... How do I return the loaded list back to the doLoad() method....